# Make code block inside HTML table cell scrollable

Tags: html, css, html-table, codeblocks

I want to find out how to make code blocks inside table cells scrollable.

**Code:**

```
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <td>
                <pre>
                    <code class="language-csharp">
                        Prism.languages.markup = {
                            'comment': /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/,
                            'prolog': /<\?[\s\S]+?\?>/,
                            'doctype': /<!DOCTYPE[\s\S]+?>/i,
                            'cdata': /<!\[CDATA\[[\s\S]*?]]>/i,
                            'tag': {
                                pattern: /<\/?(?!\d)[^\s>\/=$<]+(?:\s+[^\s>\/=]+(?:=(?:("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1|[^\s'">=]+))?)*\s*\/?>/i/<\/?(?!\d)[^\s>\/=$<]+(?:\s+[^\s>\/=]+(?:=(?:("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1|[^\s'">=]+))?)*\s*\/?>/i,
                                inside: {
                                    'tag': {
                                        pattern: /^<\/?[^\s>\/]+/i,
                                        inside: {
                                            'punctuation': /^<\/?/,
                                            'namespace': /^[^\s>\/:]+:/
                                        }
                                    },
                                    'attr-value': {
                                        pattern: /=(?:("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1|[^\s'">=]+)/i,
                                        inside: {
                                            'punctuation': [
                                                /^=/,
                                                {
                                                    pattern: /(^|[^\\])["']/,
                                                    lookbehind: true
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    'punctuation': /\/?>/,
                                    'attr-name': {
                                        pattern: /[^\s>\/]+/,
                                        inside: {
                                            'namespace': /^[^\s>\/:]+:/
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            },
                            'entity': /&#?[\da-z]{1,8};/i
                        };
                    </code>
                </pre>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <pre>
            <code class="language-csharp">
                Prism.languages.markup = {
                    'comment': /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/,
                    'prolog': /<\?[\s\S]+?\?>/,
                    'doctype': /<!DOCTYPE[\s\S]+?>/i,
                    'cdata': /<!\[CDATA\[[\s\S]*?]]>/i,
                    'tag': {
                        pattern: /<\/?(?!\d)[^\s>\/=$<]+(?:\s+[^\s>\/=]+(?:=(?:("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1|[^\s'">=]+))?)*\s*\/?>/i/<\/?(?!\d)[^\s>\/=$<]+(?:\s+[^\s>\/=]+(?:=(?:("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1|[^\s'">=]+))?)*\s*\/?>/i,
                        inside: {
                            'tag': {
                                pattern: /^<\/?[^\s>\/]+/i,
                                inside: {
                                    'punctuation': /^<\/?/,
                                    'namespace': /^[^\s>\/:]+:/
                                }
                            },
                            'attr-value': {
                                pattern: /=(?:("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1|[^\s'">=]+)/i,
                                inside: {
                                    'punctuation': [
                                        /^=/,
                                        {
                                            pattern: /(^|[^\\])["']/,
                                            lookbehind: true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            'punctuation': /\/?>/,
                            'attr-name': {
                                pattern: /[^\s>\/]+/,
                                inside: {
                                    'namespace': /^[^\s>\/:]+:/
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    'entity': /&#?[\da-z]{1,8};/i
                };
            </code>
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/sergiutripon/mubrebmw/1/

As you can see at the link above, the code inside the table cell isn't scrollable and enlarges the body of the web page.

The code block below the table is simply inside a div, and is scrollable.

I would like to achieve the same behaviour as the code block outside of the table for the code block inside the table, but I'm not really sure how.

Comment: You can add an explicit width and `overflow: auto`.

Comment: @Phix I don't want to add a fixed width, and `width: 100%` or `width: auto` doesn't work.

Comment: just `<code style="overflow: auto;">...` [**chick this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mubrebmw/2/)

Comment: @SaidbakR The fiddle doesn't work. The content is not scrollable, it exceeds the width of the container and produces a scrollbar on the whole web page which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is add a height of what you like to the `<pre>` and an `overflow` with the value of `scroll`:

```html
<pre style="height: 500px; overflow: scroll;">
```

Don't do inline styles they slow your page down, look bad and is bad practice. 
so here is the `css`:

```css
pre {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting a div block inside the table cell with overflow:scroll property should do the trick.

```
<td><div style="overflow:scroll;">Your Scrollable Content</div></td>
```

Comment: Try adding a max-height and max-width to your table cell. https://jsfiddle.net/Hoargarth/4zvsdn8z/ (Sorry that my this fiddle looks somewhat sh** but using jsfiddle on mobile is just terrible...)

Comment: I don't want to use fixed widths